# How to use Ajax on Rails to copy a field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to use ajax to copy the value from a field, after the user has selected an option.

Right now I'm not using ajax and my code is something like this:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <%= f.label :inscription_end, "End Date" %>
      <div class="input-group datetime">
        <%= f.text_field :inscription_end, :value => @ofer.inscription_end.blank? ? nil : l(@ofer.inscription_end, :format => :long), :"data-date-before" => "inscription_begin", :id => "inscription_end", :title => tooltip_error_title(@ofer, :inscription_end), class: "form-control", disabled: disabled_it_result_ended %>it
        <span class="input-group-addon"><%= glyph(:calendar) %></span>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <%= f.label :date_documents_sending, "End date to receive documents" %>
      <div class="input-group datetime">
        <%= f.text_field :date_documents_sending, :value => @ofer.inscription_end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Is there a way to automatically send the input from `:inscription_end`, to `:date_documents_sending` as soon as the user selects the `:inscription_end` from the calendar?

Comment: What do you mean "send the input"? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to mirror the 2 text fields. When the user selects a date from the first one, I want that information showing on the second one.

Comment: Ok. There is no _automatic_ way of doing that in rails. You have to write some JavaScript to do that.

Answer (score 0):

All this does is populate the date.documents_sending with the selected value
Using Jquery "ensure your elements are correct".

`$(".input-group datetime").change(function (){
        var selectedDate = $(".input-group datetime option:selected").val();
        $(".date_documents_sending").html(selectedDate);
)};`